# Remove Node from XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, element, xmlserializer

I want to save a WCF request as file to a catalog, but when the file(xml) is created from the XmlSerializer it adds a Node to the XML file which I do not want. Called ("ProjectInRequest"). I do not want to have this node in the created output file. 
How can I remove it in the most sufficent way?

I have tried to load the whole document in XmlDocument where the file should be created, but the creation of the file does not happen until the response is returned. There fore the whole service fails.

```
namespace SymbrioProjectIn
{

    public partial class SymbrioProjectIn_v1
    {
        public ProjectInResponse GetSymbrioProjectInRequest(ProjectInRequest request)
        {

            if (request == null || request.SymbrioXMLProjectIn.Project == null && request.SymbrioXMLProjectIn.Routing == null )
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Request is null: You need to send info in request.");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    //All we want to do is take the Request that SAP sends and store it to a file catalog.
                    //We can after that use BizTalk to move the file too another sftp catalog for Symbrio
                    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                    String dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                    dir += "\\ProjectIn_Data";
                    string filename = dir + "\\ProjectIn.xml";
                    if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir); // inside the if statement   

                    //XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                    //Add an empty namespace and empty value
                    //ns.(string.Empty, string.Empty);
                    //XElement ProjectInRequest = new XElement("ProjectInRequest");
                    //ProjectInRequest.RemoveAll();

                    /*XmlAttributes ignore = new XmlAttributes() { XmlIgnore = true };
                    XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
                    overrides.Add(typeof(ProjectInRequest), "ProjectInRequest", ignore);*/

                    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(request.GetType(), new XmlRootAttribute("ProjectInRequest").ElementName); //Tried som code from internet  not sure what it does               
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(
                            filename,
                            FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                            FileAccess.Write,
                            FileShare.ReadWrite);
                    ser.Serialize(fs, request);                    
                    var response = new SymbrioProjectIn.ProjectInResponse{
                        SymbrioXMLProjectIn = request.SymbrioXMLProjectIn                        
                    };

                   //Looks like xmlSerialiser creates some type of namespace which I do not want.
                    //Create our own namespaces for the output
                    XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    XDoc.Load(@"D:\ServiceArea\SymbrioProjectIn\ProjectIn_Data\ProjectIn.xml");
                    XmlNodeList RemoveNodeProjectInRequest = XDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ProjectInRequest");
                    foreach (XmlNode Node in RemoveNodeProjectInRequest)
                    {
                        Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node);
                    }
                    XDoc.Save(@"D:\ServiceArea\SymbrioProjectIn\ProjectIn_Data\ProjectIn.xml"); 

                    return response;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                    throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);

                } 
            }

        } 

    }
}
```

The file that is created looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ProjectInRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="ProjectInRequest">
  <SymbrioXMLProjectIn>
    <Routing SourceValue="?" SourceType="?" DestinationValue="?" DestinationType="?" xmlns="http://www.symbrio.com/schemas/symbrioprojectin20133" />
    <Project xmlns="http://www.symbrio.com/schemas/symbrioprojectin20133">
      <CompanyCode>?</CompanyCode>
      <DivisionCode>?</DivisionCode>
      <MainProjectNo>?</MainProjectNo>
      <ProjectNo>?</ProjectNo>
      <ProjectName>?</ProjectName>
      <ProjectType>?</ProjectType>
      <PLCode>?</PLCode>
      <EmploymentNo>?</EmploymentNo>
      <Active>?</Active>
      <ActiveStart>?</ActiveStart>
      <ActiveEnd>?</ActiveEnd>
      <DeliveryAddress>?</DeliveryAddress>
      <DeliveryPostalCode>?</DeliveryPostalCode>
      <DeliveryCity>?</DeliveryCity>
      <DeliveryAddressNoteText>?</DeliveryAddressNoteText>
      <AccountRef1>?</AccountRef1>
      <AccountRef2>?</AccountRef2>
      <AccountRef3>?</AccountRef3>
      <AccountRef4>?</AccountRef4>
      <RegisteredDate>?</RegisteredDate>
      <Closed>?</Closed>
    </Project>
  </SymbrioXMLProjectIn>
</ProjectInRequest>
```

What I want is this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SymbrioXMLProjectIn>
  <Routing SourceValue="str1234" SourceType="str1234" DestinationValue="str1234" DestinationType="str1234" />
  <Project>
    <CompanyCode>str1234</CompanyCode>
    <DivisionCode>str1234</DivisionCode>
    <MainProjectNo>str1234</MainProjectNo>
    <ProjectNo>str1234</ProjectNo>
    <ProjectName>str1234</ProjectName>
    <ProjectType>str1234</ProjectType>
    <PLCode>str1234</PLCode>
    <EmploymentNo>str1234</EmploymentNo>
    <Active>str1234</Active>
    <ActiveStart>str1234</ActiveStart>
    <ActiveEnd>str1234</ActiveEnd>
    <DeliveryAddress>str1234</DeliveryAddress>
    <DeliveryPostalCode>str1234</DeliveryPostalCode>
    <DeliveryCity>str1234</DeliveryCity>
    <DeliveryAddressNoteText>str1234</DeliveryAddressNoteText>
    <AccountRef1>str1234</AccountRef1>
    <AccountRef2>str1234</AccountRef2>
    <AccountRef3>str1234</AccountRef3>
    <AccountRef4>str1234</AccountRef4>
    <RegisteredDate>str1234</RegisteredDate>
    <Closed>str1234</Closed>
  </Project>
</SymbrioXMLProjectIn>
```

ProjectInRequest - Node does not exist.

I might have missed something if so please point it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm found the solution, I XmlSeralized wrong the correct way should have been

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(request.SymbrioXMLProjectIn.GetType());
```

the bad way was

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(request.GetType());
```

Will leave this here if anyone does a dummy misstake like me.

Answer (score 0):

use xpath to extract the record you wanted

```
//*[local-name()='SymbrioXMLProjectIn']
```